# VueJS exclude a config file from being bundled

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, build, config

I'm using the `vue-webpack` template and a `appConfig.js` file to store the API url and some other variables. The API url should be changed after build.

`appConfig.js` file looks like this:

```
export { BASE_URL, ACCOUNT, NOTIFICATIONS };

const BASE_URL = 'apiurl';
const ACCOUNT = ....
```

In the app, I use this config file through an import.

```
import { BASE_URL, ACCOUNT } from '../appConfig';
```

I would like to keep this file out of the bundling process and add it in the build afterwards. I heard about `externals` in webpack conf but I can't managed to get it works with my app. Or maybe there is another way to handle this ?

Comment: You can create two separate config files like appConfig.dev.js and appConfig.build.js. Using the environment variable and little code to make your app distinguish which file should be loaded during the build of dev or production build. If you have more than two environments, you can use the same method to generate more config files

Comment: Thanks Telvin, but I would loaded the config file after the build, not during. I would exclude the config file from this build.